# cosmos-auth could not getting connect to fiware-idm

Tags: fiware-cosmos

I have registered my cosmos-auth application in fiware-idm and and when i send request :

curl -k -X POST "https://x.x.x.x:13000/cosmos-auth/v1/token" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=password&username=admin@test.com&password=1234"

It throws error:{"statusCode":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"An internal server error occurred"}

Logs generated at cosmos-auth :

info: [user --> cosmos-auth] Request: POST /cosmos-auth/v1/token
info: [user --> cosmos-auth] {"user-agent":"curl/7.29.0","host":"x.x.x.x:13000","accept":"*/*","content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","content-length":"57"}
info: [user --> cosmos-auth] grant_type=password&username=admin@test.com&password=1234
info: [cosmos-auth -> IdM] Request: POST https://x.x.x.x:3004/oauth2/token
info: [cosmos-auth -> IdM] {"Authorization":"Basic OGQ3NTI5MTYtZTJiOC00ZDJiLWI1YzEtMTA5OWNkYTQyMzk5OjZlNjhhMTI5LTc3NjQtNDk0MC04NzVmLTU1MzEwMTUxODI3MQ==","Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Content-Length":57}
info: [cosmos-auth -> IdM] grant_type=password&username=admin@test.com&password=1234
(node:3250) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
error: Could not connect to the IdM

Please provide some help?

Comment: Hi Damini, It seems to be a connection problem, please be sure that your cosmos and IDM instance have a communication between them in their correspondent ports. Also you can test if ya can get a token from the IDM using your credentials, and then verify where the problem is allocated.

Comment: They are communicating but when i request to generate token for cosmos-auth its not able to connect to fiware idm.i have also checked client id and secret id and updated my conf file in cosmos-auth but still same issue.